# Chapter five of Spivak's: the second lemma

Tags: calculus, limits

In chapter five of Spivak's, the chapter on limits, Spivak lists a lemma (the second out of three total) that is the following:

> if $|x-x_0|< \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)})$ and $|y-y_0|< \frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0|+1}$, then $|xy-x_0y_0|< \epsilon$

My question is, wouldn't $|y-y_0|< \frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0|+1}$ have to be $|y-y_0| < \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0|+1})$ for the lemma above to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The estimate in the proof has $x$ and $y$ appearing in non-symmetric fashion.

Comment: Could you explain why they are appearing in a non-symmetric manner?

Comment: Follow the proof. You can see that he never needs to know $|y-y_0|<1$. But he did use $|x-x_0|<1$.

Comment: I did follow the proof, and my problem occurs in this step: $(1+|x_0|)$ * $\frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$ + $|y_0|$ * $\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}$ = $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ + $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: How does it cancel out in the second part of the equation?

Comment: It doesn't cancel, but $|y_0|+1> |y_0|$, so the inequality works fine. It's like saying $1/3<1/2$. He doesn't have $=$, I hope; he should have $<$.

Comment: He does, that was my mistake. The proof makes sense now, thank you

Comment: Sure thing! Keep going!